# GetCurrentDirectory buffer doesn't return the right value

Tags: c++, c, windows, buffer

I have an issue with `GetCurrentDirectory()`, and i don't really understand why. The thing i don't understand is that it works for XP but not for Seven (or at least on my computer). There is my code:

```
char dir_name[1024]; // as a global variable
int get_files() {
// ...
DWORD dwRet;
dwRet = GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, dir_name);
printf("%s\n",dir_name);
printf("%d\n",dwRet);
//...
}
```

This code will return:

`printf("%s\n",dir_name);` -> `return "c"`

`printf("%d\n",dwRet);` -> `42` (which is the right length of the string that should be returned)

I don't understand why dir_name only takes the value "c".

Comment: Looks like unicode problem. I mean, your program compiles in a wide-char configuration, hence `GetCurrentDirectory` expands into `GetCurrentDirectoryW`. Try `GetCurrentDirectoryA` instead of `GetCurrentDirectory`.

Comment: Using GetCurrentDirectoryA changed nothing unfortunatly.

Comment: 42 is always the right return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, the result is Unicode in Windows Seven! and after each ascii character of this function there is zero. And you are printing it by `printf`. You should use wide-char functions in your program. Like `wprintf`.

Try below code: (Tested in Visual Studio 2008 + Windows 7)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wchar.h>

WCHAR dir_name[1024]; // as a global variable

int get_files()
{
    // ...
    DWORD dwRet;
    dwRet = GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, dir_name);
    wprintf(L"%s\n", dir_name);
    printf("%d\n", dwRet);
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At the end, disable UNICODE was the best way.

Comment: There is NO best way at all ;-)

Comment: Note: XP supports Unicode as well (it's in fact the native charset); it's just that _your_ compiler settings differed on XP and 7. The char type that will "always" work is `TCHAR`, which is defined as `char` or `WCHAR` to match the `UNICODE` setting.

Comment: I think TCHAR is preferred here to WCHAR, then it'll work in either Unicode or ANSI...

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure, but could it be `GetCurrentDirectory()` returns 2-byte chars under win7?

In such case you'll be getting a 0 in each second bytes of the char array returned.

So you should use a wide-char aware version of the `printf()` function such as `wprintf()`.

Also I wonder whether the compiler wouldn't have warned you about something being wrong regarding types.

Answer (score 1):

what compiler are you using? Under Visual C++ 2005, GetCurrentDirectory is a macro that resolves to GetCurrentDirectoryW if UNICODE macro is defined and to GetCurrentDirectoryA  otherwise. Do you have UNICODE defined by any chance?

Comment: On the other hand, if it expanded to `GetCurrentDirectoryW` he would have a compilation error, because he would be passing a `char *` to a `wchar_t *` parameter, and there's no cast to force the conversion.

Comment: I agree Matteo, and such error does show under Visual 2005. dyesdyes - you might also try running your application with administrative rights, or try disabling UAC. I tested your code under Win7 and it works fine for Unicode and Non-Unicode builds, but I have disabled UAC long time ago.

Comment: Thanks for the tips but i have disabled UAC long time ago as well. How can i run my application (console application) with admin right ?

Comment: if you have disabled UAC then it will not help anyway. But you can right click on your application in Explorer and choose Run As Administrator (not sure about name, I dont use english windows). The fact that your application is using GetCurrentDirectoryW function in non unicode build is very strange, it looks like you are linking against wrong library or maybe using bad dll, I'am not sure how this happens.

Comment: You can freely use the `*W` functions in non-Unicode builds, and the `*A` functions in Unicode builds. The non-suffix versions are mere defines.